# Asynchronous Javascript: Unexpected result

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm teaching myself asynchronous JS and wrote a small test program to help me better understand how it works.

My expectations with this code was that the even numbers would test out of sequence since I put a delay in the function "TestPrime()". However, when the code runs, the numbers run in sequence. In other words, I was expecting something along the lines of:

3 is prime
5 is prime
2 is prime
...

```
async function TestPrime(num) {

    for(var i = 2; i < num; i++){

        let res = num % i;

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            setTimeout(()=>{}, 1500);
        }

        if (res == 0) {
            return ({number: num, prime: false});
        }
    }

    return ({ number: num, prime: true});
}

const f = ()=>{
    for (var i = 2; i <= 50; i++){

        if (TestPrime(i).then(p => { 
            if (p.prime)
                console.log('%s is prime', p.number);
            else    
                console.log('%s is NOT prime', p.number);
        }));
    }
}

f();
```

I'm sure this is just a noob misunderstanding of asynchronous JS programming but I would be much obliged if someone out there could set me straight.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: setTimeout does not delay the execution of the current function. It executes the function passed as an argument (in your case an empty function) after the specified delay

Comment: @BaliBalo (facepalm) - Doh! Of course! Is there a way for me to pause within the function, then?

Comment: A common trick is `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))` as pointed out in one of the answers

Comment: An asynchronous functions execution will only ever halt at `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(()=>{}, 1500);
```

does nothing. It's effectively a NO-OP.

If you want to delay an async method, you can define a delay method as follows:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

This returns a `Promise` that resolves after `ms` milliseconds.

It can be used as follows:

```
async function foo(){
   // do something
   await delay(1500);
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: For my own edification, could the function you provided be re-written as: const delay = async ms => (setTimeout(()=>{}, ms)); ?

Comment: @Ishmael No. In your example, after a timeout of `ms`, the callback `()=>{}` is called by `setTimeout`. The callback has no effects. It does nothing. Await ***relies*** on `Promise` to work. `setTimeout` has nothing to do with promises. In order to bridge this gap, it's required to use the `Promise` constructor. The promise constructor takes a function which is immediately invoked, and the framework passes in 2 functions, `resolve` and `reject`. When either of these is called, the Promise resolves successfully or errors. So, we `setTimeout` to call this `resolve` after `ms`...

Comment: @Ishmael ...meaning that the Promise successfully resolves after the time period.

Comment: @Ishmael If you want to learn more about interfacing `async/await` code with older forms of asynchrony (e.g. `setTimeout`, callbacks etc), then you need to understand how `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})` operates. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you are delaying is the calling of `()=>{}` — a function which does **nothing**.

`setTimeout` isn't a sleep function. That's the point of being asynchronous: Everything else carries on without waiting.

---

To have an actual delay, you need to stop your promise from resolving until the timeout is complete.

With classic promise syntax that would look like this:

```js
function TestPrime(num) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      let res = num % i;
      if (num % 2 == 0) {
        return setTimeout(() => resolve({
          number: num,
        }), 1500);
      }
      if (res == 0) {
        return resolve({
          number: num,
        });
      }
    }
    resolve({
      number: num,
    });
  });
}
const f = () => {
  for (var i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
    if (TestPrime(i).then(p => {
        if (p.prime) console.log('%s is prime', p.number);
        else console.log('%s is NOT prime', p.number);
      }));
  }
};
f();
```